# how to bind menu xml file to list view in android

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have menu resource like  this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group
         android:id="@+id/nav_drawer">
        <item android:title="my profile" android:icon="@drawable/ic_user"/>
        <item android:title="my_msg" android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_email"/>
    </group>
</menu>
```

how can i bind this xml to the my_list in main_activity.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/my_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: You need to use it as an inflated view from within your listview adapter class, I have never tried to use a menu XML file in this manner before however so I am not sure how well this will work out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to achieve a [contextual](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) Menu in your activity or fragment. Using context menu is the solution for you according to me.

Comment: @Mohammad Gholami edited the answer with link check it.